# Merge sort in PHP 5

Tags: beginner, php, array, mergesort, php5

I have this small program in PHP implementing merge sort. I used one rather simple run time optimisation via using one additional array which allows faster merge operations:

```
function merge_impl(&$source,
                    &$target,
                    $source_offset,
                    $target_offset,
                    $left_run_length,
                    $right_run_length) {
    $target_index = $target_offset;
    $left = $source_offset;
    $left_bound = $left + $left_run_length;
    $right = $left_bound;
    $right_bound = $right + $right_run_length;

    while ($left != $left_bound and $right != $right_bound) {
        $target[$target_index++] =
                $source[$right] < $source[$left] ?
                $source[$right++] :
                $source[$left++];
    }

    while ($left != $left_bound) {
        $target[$target_index++] = $source[$left++];
    }

    while ($right != $right_bound) {
        $target[$target_index++] = $source[$right++];
    }
}

function mergesort_impl(&$source,
                        &$target,
                        $source_offset,
                        $target_offset,
                        $range_length) {
    if ($range_length < 2) {
        return;
    }

    $middle = intval($range_length / 2);

    mergesort_impl($target,
                   $source,
                   $target_offset,
                   $source_offset,
                   $middle);

    mergesort_impl($target,
                   $source,
                   $target_offset + $middle,
                   $source_offset + $middle,
                   $range_length - $middle);

    merge_impl($source,
               $target,
               $source_offset,
               $target_offset,
               $middle,
               $range_length - $middle);
}

function mergesort_ex(&$arr, $from_index, $to_index) {
    $range_length = $to_index - $from_index;
    if ($range_length < 2) {
        return;
    }

    $aux = array_merge(array(), 
                       array_slice($arr, 
                                   $from_index, 
                                   $range_length));
    mergesort_impl($aux, $arr, 0, $from_index, $range_length);
}

function mergesort(&$arr) {
    mergesort_ex($arr, 0, count($arr));
}

$arr1 = array(23, 20, 4, -1, 5, 43, 22);
echo "The entire array is: ";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); ++$i) {
    echo $arr1[$i] . " ";
}

echo "<br>";

mergesort_ex($arr1, 1, 6);

echo "Sorted array slice A[1, 6]: ";

for ($i = 1; $i < 6; ++$i) {
    echo "$arr1[$i] ";
}
```

As I have almost no experience with PHP, please tell me anything that comes to mind (e.g. API, naming/coding conventions, etc.).

Comment: can you provide an implementation and/or explanation?

Comment: @pppp The idea above is to use two arrays: one source array and one target array. At all recursion levels I merge the runs residing in the source array into a single merged run in the target array. The topmost call is such that the entire sorted range ends up in the array that was passed to the sort routine. This arrangement allows me to strip some unnecessary computation from the merging operation.

Comment: I may be missing the point of this function, but doesn't this basically replicate `$result = array_slice($arr1,1,5); sort($result); echo implode(' ', $result);` ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that [you have quite a bit of experience with mergesort](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a58360%20mergesort) in various programming languages. While it may obviously be deemed a bit tangential to the purpose of StackOverflow I can’t help but notice [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64017594/1575353) suggests a single recursive function to handle the task with many fewer variables.

As was suggested by CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ [in a comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143713/merge-sort-in-php-5#comment269796_143713) PHP does have its [`sort()`](https://php.net/sort) method though the [Notes section](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php#refsect1-function.sort-notes) of the PHP documentation for that function states:

> **Note**: Like most PHP sorting functions, **sort()** uses an implementation of [» Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). The pivot is chosen in the middle of the partition resulting in an optimal time for already sorted arrays. This is however an implementation detail you shouldn't rely on.

<sup>[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php#refsect1-function.sort-notes)</sup>

I see you have experience with many programming languages, from Perl to c to Java, and have used logical operators like logical `AND` in c-based languages - i.e. `&&` (e.g. in [this java post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175392/uni-and-bidirectional-beam-search-in-java)). PHP has [two variations for logical `AND`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) i.e. `and` and `&&` (as well as for logical `OR`: `or` and `||`).  Note that [`and` has lower precedence than many other operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) including assignment - `=`.

This line doesn’t appear to have any issues with precedence:

> ```
> while ($left != $left_bound and $right != $right_bound) {
> ```

Though as [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2803576/1575353) illustrates it is wise to use caution and consider which variations to use thoughtfully.

While it doesn’t really concern the algorithm, the code to output the array can be simplified- e.g:

> ```
> for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); ++$i) {
>     echo $arr1[$i] . " ";
> }
> ```

Can be simplified using [`foreach`](https://php.net/foreach)

```
foreach ($arr1 as $element) {
    echo $element . " ";
}
```

Or using [`implode()`](https://php.net/implode) (or its alias [`join()`](https://php.net/join)):

```
echo implode(" ", $arr1) . " ";
```

Similarly-

> ```
> for ($i = 1; $i < 6; ++$i) {
>     echo "$arr1[$i] ";
> }
> ```

Can be simplified with `implode()` and `array_slice()`:

```
echo implode(" ", array_slice($arr1, 1, 5)) . " ";
```

Or even simpler, since it prints to the end of the array:

```
echo implode(" ", array_slice($arr1, 1)) . " ";
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php#refsect1-function.sort-notes</sub>