# Uni- and bidirectional beam search in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, pathfinding

## What

Beam search is a best-first search algorithm that does not necessary find an optimal path, yet has smaller memory-footprint. In this program, I attempted to answer a question how does it compare to A* and whether bidirectional beam search provides any improvement over unidirectional variant what comes to running time and optimality of the result path.

## Code

**BeamSearchPathfinder.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.beamsearch;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;
import net.coderodde.graph.AbstractGraph;

public final class BeamSearchPathfinder implements Pathfinder {

    /**
     * The default width of the beam.
     */
    private static final int DEFAULT_BEAM_WIDTH = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    /**
     * The minimum allowed beam width.
     */
    private static final int MINIMUM_BEAM_WIDHT = 1;

    /**
     * The current beam width.
     */
    private int beamWidth = DEFAULT_BEAM_WIDTH;

    public int getBeamWidth() {
        return beamWidth;
    }

    public void setBeamWidth(int beamWidth) {
        this.beamWidth = Math.max(beamWidth, MINIMUM_BEAM_WIDHT);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Integer> search(AbstractGraph graph,
                                Integer sourceNode,
                                Integer targetNode, 
                                HeuristicFunction<Integer> heuristicFunction) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(graph, "The input graph is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(sourceNode, "The source node is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(targetNode, "The target node is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(heuristicFunction,
                               "The heuristic function is null.");

        checkNodes(graph, sourceNode, targetNode);

        Queue<HeapNode> open           = new PriorityQueue<>();
        Set<Integer> closed            = new HashSet<>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> parents  = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, Double> distances = new HashMap<>();

        open.add(new HeapNode(sourceNode, 0.0));
        parents.put(sourceNode, null);
        distances.put(sourceNode, 0.0);

        while (!open.isEmpty()) {
            Integer currentNode = open.remove().node;

            if (currentNode.equals(targetNode)) {
                return tracebackPath(targetNode, parents);
            }

            if (closed.contains(currentNode)) {
                continue;
            }

            closed.add(currentNode);
            List<Integer> successorNodes = getSuccessors(graph,
                                                         currentNode,
                                                         targetNode,
                                                         distances,
                                                         heuristicFunction,
                                                         beamWidth);
            for (Integer childNode : successorNodes) {
                if (closed.contains(childNode)) {
                    continue;
                }

                double tentativeDistance = 
                        distances.get(currentNode) +
                        graph.getEdgeWeight(currentNode, childNode);

                if (!distances.containsKey(childNode)
                        || distances.get(childNode) > tentativeDistance) {
                    distances.put(childNode, tentativeDistance);
                    parents.put(childNode, currentNode);
                    open.add(
                            new HeapNode(childNode, 
                                         tentativeDistance + 
                                         heuristicFunction.estimate(
                                                 childNode, 
                                                 targetNode)));
                }
            }
        }

        throw new PathNotFoundException(
                "Path from " + sourceNode + " to " + targetNode + 
                " not found.");
    }

    private static List<Integer> 
        getSuccessors(AbstractGraph graph,
                      Integer currentNode,
                      Integer targetNode,
                      Map<Integer, Double> distances,
                      HeuristicFunction<Integer> heuristicFunction,
                      int beamWidth) {
        List<Integer> successors = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Integer, Double> costMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (Integer successor : graph.getChildrenOf(currentNode)) {
            successors.add(successor);
            costMap.put(
                    successor, 
                    distances.get(currentNode) + 
                        graph.getEdgeWeight(currentNode, successor) +
                        heuristicFunction.estimate(successor, targetNode));
        }

        Collections.sort(successors, (a, b) -> {
            return Double.compare(costMap.get(a), costMap.get(b));
        });

        return successors.subList(0, Math.min(successors.size(), beamWidth));
    }

    private static final class HeapNode implements Comparable<HeapNode> {
        Integer node;
        double fScore;

        HeapNode(Integer node, double fScore) {
            this.node = node;
            this.fScore = fScore;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(HeapNode o) {
            return Double.compare(fScore, o.fScore);
        }
    }
}
```

**BidirectionalBeamSearchPathfinder.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.beamsearch;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;
import net.coderodde.graph.AbstractGraph;

public final class BidirectionalBeamSearchPathfinder implements Pathfinder {

    /**
     * The default width of the beam.
     */
    private static final int DEFAULT_BEAM_WIDTH = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    /**
     * The minimum allowed beam width.
     */
    private static final int MINIMUM_BEAM_WIDHT = 1;

    /**
     * The current beam width.
     */
    private int beamWidth = DEFAULT_BEAM_WIDTH;

    public int getBeamWidth() {
        return beamWidth;
    }

    public void setBeamWidth(int beamWidth) {
        this.beamWidth = Math.max(beamWidth, MINIMUM_BEAM_WIDHT);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Integer> search(AbstractGraph graph, 
                                Integer sourceNode, 
                                Integer targetNode, 
                                HeuristicFunction<Integer> heuristicFunction) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(graph, "The input graph is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(sourceNode, "The source node is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(targetNode, "The target node is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(heuristicFunction,
                               "The heuristic function is null.");

        checkNodes(graph, sourceNode, targetNode);

        Queue<HeapNode> openForward            = new PriorityQueue<>();
        Queue<HeapNode> openBackward           = new PriorityQueue<>();
        Set<Integer> closedForward             = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Integer> closedBackward            = new HashSet<>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> parentsForward   = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> parentsBackward  = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, Double> distancesForward  = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, Double> distancesBackward = new HashMap<>();

        double bestPathLength = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        Integer touchNode = null;

        openForward.add(new HeapNode(sourceNode, 0.0));
        openBackward.add(new HeapNode(targetNode, 0.0));
        parentsForward.put(sourceNode, null);
        parentsBackward.put(targetNode, null);
        distancesForward.put(sourceNode, 0.0);
        distancesBackward.put(targetNode, 0.0);

        while (!openForward.isEmpty() && !openBackward.isEmpty()) {
            if (touchNode != null) {
                Integer minA = openForward.peek().node;
                Integer minB = openBackward.peek().node;

                double distanceA = distancesForward.get(minA) +
                                   heuristicFunction.estimate(minA, targetNode);
                double distanceB = distancesBackward.get(minB) +
                                   heuristicFunction.estimate(minB, sourceNode);

                if (bestPathLength <= Math.max(distanceA, distanceB)) {
                    return tracebackPath(touchNode, 
                                         parentsForward, 
                                         parentsBackward);
                }
            }

            if (openForward.size() + closedForward.size() <
                    openBackward.size() + closedBackward.size()) {
                Integer currentNode = openForward.remove().node;

                if (closedForward.contains(currentNode)) {
                    continue;
                }

                closedForward.add(currentNode);

                List<Integer> successors = 
                        getForwardSuccessors(graph,
                                             openBackward.peek().node,
                                             currentNode, 
                                             targetNode,
                                             distancesForward,
                                             heuristicFunction,
                                             beamWidth);

                for (Integer childNode : successors) {
                    if (closedForward.contains(childNode)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    double tentativeScore = 
                            distancesForward.get(currentNode) +
                            graph.getEdgeWeight(currentNode, childNode);

                    if (!distancesForward.containsKey(childNode) 
                            || distancesForward.get(childNode) > 
                               tentativeScore) {
                        distancesForward.put(childNode, tentativeScore);
                        parentsForward.put(childNode, currentNode);
                        openForward.add(
                                new HeapNode(
                                        childNode, 
                                        tentativeScore + heuristicFunction
                                        .estimate(childNode, targetNode)));

                        if (closedBackward.contains(childNode)) {
                            double pathLength = 
                                    distancesBackward.get(childNode) +
                                    tentativeScore;

                            if (bestPathLength > pathLength) {
                                bestPathLength = pathLength;
                                touchNode = childNode;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Integer currentNode = openBackward.remove().node;

                if (closedBackward.contains(currentNode)) {
                    continue;
                }

                closedBackward.add(currentNode);

                List<Integer> successors = 
                        getBackwardSuccessors(graph,
                                              openForward.peek().node,
                                              currentNode, 
                                              sourceNode,
                                              distancesBackward,
                                              heuristicFunction,
                                              beamWidth);

                for (Integer parentNode : successors) {
                    if (closedBackward.contains(parentNode)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    double tentativeScore = 
                            distancesBackward.get(currentNode) +
                            graph.getEdgeWeight(parentNode, currentNode);

                    if (!distancesBackward.containsKey(parentNode)
                            || distancesBackward.get(parentNode) >
                               tentativeScore) {
                        distancesBackward.put(parentNode, tentativeScore);
                        parentsBackward.put(parentNode, currentNode);
                        openBackward.add(
                                new HeapNode(
                                    parentNode,
                                tentativeScore + heuristicFunction
                                .estimate(parentNode, sourceNode)));

                        if (closedForward.contains(parentNode)) {
                            double pathLength = 
                                    distancesForward.get(parentNode) + 
                                    tentativeScore;

                            if (bestPathLength > pathLength) {
                                bestPathLength = pathLength;
                                touchNode = parentNode;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        throw new PathNotFoundException(
                "Target node " + targetNode + " is not reachable from " +
                sourceNode);
    }

    private static List<Integer> 
        getForwardSuccessors(AbstractGraph graph,
                             Integer backwardTop,
                             Integer currentNode,
                             Integer targetNode,
                             Map<Integer, Double> distances,
                             HeuristicFunction<Integer> heuristicFunction,
                             int beamWidth) {
        List<Integer> successors = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Integer, Double> costMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (Integer successor : graph.getChildrenOf(currentNode)) {
            successors.add(successor);
            costMap.put(
                    successor,
                    distances.get(currentNode) + 
                        graph.getEdgeWeight(currentNode, successor) +
                        heuristicFunction.estimate(successor, backwardTop));
        }

        Collections.sort(successors, (a, b) -> {
            return Double.compare(costMap.get(a), costMap.get(b));
        });

        return successors.subList(0, Math.min(successors.size(), 
                                              beamWidth));
    }

    private static List<Integer>
            getBackwardSuccessors(AbstractGraph graph,
                                  Integer forwardTop,
                                  Integer currentNode, 
                                  Integer sourceNode,
                                  Map<Integer, Double> distances,
                                  HeuristicFunction<Integer> heuristicFunction,
                                  int beamWidth) {
        List<Integer> successors = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Integer, Double> costMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (Integer successor : graph.getParentsOf(currentNode)) {
            successors.add(successor);
            costMap.put(
                    successor,
                    distances.get(currentNode) +
                        graph.getEdgeWeight(successor, currentNode) +
                        heuristicFunction.estimate(successor, forwardTop));
        }

        Collections.sort(successors, (a, b) -> {
            return Double.compare(costMap.get(a), costMap.get(b));
        });

        return successors.subList(0, Math.min(successors.size(),
                                              beamWidth));
    }

    private static final class HeapNode implements Comparable<HeapNode> {
        Integer node;
        double fScore;

        HeapNode(Integer node, double fScore) {
            this.node = node;
            this.fScore = fScore;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(HeapNode o) {
            return Double.compare(fScore, o.fScore);
        }
    }
}
```

**Coordinates.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.beamsearch;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public final class Coordinates {

    private final Map<Integer, Point2D.Double> map = new HashMap<>();

    public Point2D.Double get(Integer node) {
        return map.get(node);
    }

    public void put(Integer node, Point2D.Double point) {
        map.put(node, point);
    }
}
```

**DefaultHeuristicFunction.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.beamsearch;

import java.util.Objects;

public final class DefaultHeuristicFunction 
        implements HeuristicFunction<Integer> {

    private final Coordinates coordinates;

    public DefaultHeuristicFunction(Coordinates coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = 
                Objects.requireNonNull(coordinates, 
                                       "The coordinate function is null.");
    }

    @Override
    public double estimate(Integer source, Integer target) {
        return coordinates.get(source).distance(coordinates.get(target));
    }
}
```

**Demo.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.beamsearch;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import net.coderodde.graph.AbstractGraph;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraph;

public final class Demo {

    /**
     * The width of the plane containing all the graph nodes.
     */
    private static final double GRAPH_LAYOUT_WIDTH  = 1000.0;

    /**
     * The height of the plane containing all the graph nodes.
     */
    private static final double GRAPH_LAYOUT_HEIGHT = 1000.0;

    /**
     * Given two nodes {@code u} and {@code v}, the cost of the arc
     * {@code (u,v)} will be their Euclidean distance times this factor.
     */
    private static final double ARC_LENGTH_FACTOR = 1.2;

    /**
     * The number of nodes in the graph.
     */
    private static final int NODES = 250_000;

    /**
     * The number of arcs in the graph.
     */
    private static final int ARCS = 1_500_000;

    /**
     * The beam width used in the demonstration.
     */
    private static final int BEAM_WIDTH = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Random random = new Random(seed);
        System.out.println("Seed = " + seed);
        GraphData data = createDirectedGraph(NODES, ARCS, random);
        warmup(data.graph, data.heuristicFunction, new Random(seed));
        benchmark(data.graph, data.heuristicFunction, new Random(seed));
    }

    private static final void 
        warmup(DirectedGraph graph, 
               HeuristicFunction<Integer> heuristicFunction,
               Random random) {
        perform(graph, heuristicFunction, random, false);
    }

    private static final void 
        benchmark(DirectedGraph graph, 
                  HeuristicFunction<Integer> heuristicFunction,
                  Random random) {
        perform(graph, heuristicFunction, random, true);
    }

    private static final void 
        perform(DirectedGraph graph, 
                HeuristicFunction<Integer> heuristicFunction,
                Random random,
                boolean output) {
        Integer sourceNode = random.nextInt(graph.size());
        Integer targetNode = random.nextInt(graph.size());

        BeamSearchPathfinder finder1 = new BeamSearchPathfinder();
        BidirectionalBeamSearchPathfinder finder2 = 
                new BidirectionalBeamSearchPathfinder();

        finder1.setBeamWidth(BEAM_WIDTH);
        finder2.setBeamWidth(BEAM_WIDTH);

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Integer> path1 = finder1.search(graph,
                                             sourceNode,
                                             targetNode,
                                             heuristicFunction);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (output) {
            System.out.println(finder1.getClass().getSimpleName() + ":");
            System.out.println("Path: " + path1 + ", length = " +
                               getPathLength(path1, graph));
            System.out.println("Time: " + (end - start) + " milliseconds.");
        }

        finder1.setBeamWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Integer> optimalPath = finder1.search(graph, 
                                                   sourceNode, 
                                                   targetNode, 
                                                   heuristicFunction);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (output) {
            System.out.println("A*:");
            System.out.println("Path: " + optimalPath + ", length = " +
                              getPathLength(optimalPath, graph));
            System.out.println("Time: " + (end - start) + " milliseconds.");
        }

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Integer> path2 = finder2.search(graph,
                                             sourceNode, 
                                             targetNode, 
                                             heuristicFunction);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (output) {
            System.out.println(finder2.getClass().getSimpleName() + ":");
            System.out.println("Path: " + path2 + ", length = " + 
                               getPathLength(path2, graph));
            System.out.println("Time: " + (end - start) + " milliseconds.");
        }
    }

    private static double getPathLength(List<Integer> path,
                                        AbstractGraph graph) {
        double sum = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < path.size() - 1; ++i) {
            sum += graph.getEdgeWeight(path.get(i), path.get(i + 1));
        }

        return sum;
    }

    private static final class GraphData {
        DirectedGraph graph;
        HeuristicFunction<Integer> heuristicFunction;
    }

    private static final Coordinates getRandomCoordinates(AbstractGraph graph,
                                                          Random random) {
        Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates();

        for (Integer node : graph.getAllNodes()) {
            coordinates.put(node, createRandomPoint(GRAPH_LAYOUT_WIDTH,
                                                    GRAPH_LAYOUT_HEIGHT,
                                                    random));
        }

        return coordinates;
    }

    private static final Point2D.Double
         createRandomPoint(double graphLayoutWidth,
                           double graphLayoutHeight,
                           Random random) {
        return new Point2D.Double(random.nextDouble() * graphLayoutWidth,
                                  random.nextDouble() * graphLayoutHeight);
    }

    private static final GraphData createDirectedGraph(int nodes,
                                                       int arcs,
                                                       Random random) {
        DirectedGraph graph = new DirectedGraph();

        for (int node = 0; node < nodes; ++node) {
            graph.addNode(node);
        }

        Coordinates coordinates = getRandomCoordinates(graph, random);
        HeuristicFunction<Integer> heuristicFunction =
                new DefaultHeuristicFunction(coordinates);

        for (int arc = 0; arc < arcs; ++arc) {
            Integer source = random.nextInt(nodes);
            Integer target = random.nextInt(nodes);

            double euclideanDistance = heuristicFunction.estimate(source,
                                                                  target);

            graph.addEdge(source,
                          target, 
                          ARC_LENGTH_FACTOR * euclideanDistance);
        }

        GraphData data = new GraphData();
        data.graph = graph;
        data.heuristicFunction = heuristicFunction;
        return data;
    }
}
```

**HeuristicFunction.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.beamsearch;

/**
 * This interface defines the API for heuristic functions.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @param <Node> the actual node type.
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 10, 2017)
 */
public interface HeuristicFunction<Node> {

    /**
     * Returns an optimistic estimate for the path from {@code source} to 
     * {@code target}.
     * 
     * @param source the source node.
     * @param target the target node.
     * @return distance estimate.
     */
    public double estimate(Node source, Node target);
}
```

**PathNotFoundException.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.beamsearch;

public final class PathNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public PathNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

**Pathfinder.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.beamsearch;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import net.coderodde.graph.AbstractGraph;

public interface Pathfinder {

    /**
     * Searches for a path from {@code source} to {@code target} in 
     * {@code graph} using {@code heuristicFunction} as a guide.
     * 
     * @param graph             the graph to search in.
     * @param source            the source (start) node.
     * @param target            the target (goal) node.
     * @param heuristicFunction the heuristic function.
     * @return 
     */
    public List<Integer> search(AbstractGraph graph,
                                Integer source, 
                                Integer target,
                                HeuristicFunction<Integer> heuristicFunction);

    default List<Integer> tracebackPath(Integer target,
                                        Map<Integer, Integer> parents) {
        List<Integer> path = new ArrayList<>();
        Integer currentNode = target;

        while (currentNode != null) {
            path.add(currentNode);
            currentNode = parents.get(currentNode);
        }

        Collections.<Integer>reverse(path);
        return path;
    }

    default List<Integer> tracebackPath(Integer touch, 
                                        Map<Integer, Integer> forwardParents,
                                        Map<Integer, Integer> backwardParents) {
        List<Integer> prefixPath = tracebackPath(touch, forwardParents);
        Integer currentNode = backwardParents.get(touch);

        while (currentNode != null) {
            prefixPath.add(currentNode);
            currentNode = backwardParents.get(currentNode);
        }

        return prefixPath;
    }

    /**
     * Makes sure that both {@code source} and {@code target} are in the
     * {@code graph}.
     * 
     * @param graph  the graph.
     * @param source the source node.
     * @param target the target node.
     */
    default void checkNodes(AbstractGraph graph, Integer source, Integer target) {
        if (!graph.hasNode(source)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The source node " + source + " is not in the graph.");
        }

        if (!graph.hasNode(target)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The target node " + target + " is not in the graph.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Dependency** This program relies on [this Maven project](https://github.com/coderodde/GraphDatastruct).

## Critique request

Please tell me anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks good, I don't have much to say beyond some superficial syntax/formatting things:

---

Typo in `BeamSearchPathfinder` and `BidirectionalBeamSearchPathfinder`:

```
    private static final int MINIMUM_BEAM_WIDHT = 1;
```

`WIDHT` -> `WIDTH` here and in `setBeamWidth()`

---

```
open.add(
        new HeapNode(childNode, 
                     tentativeDistance + 
                     heuristicFunction.estimate(
                                 childNode, 
                                 targetNode)));
```

Much as I love Lisp, and this is totally subjective, but I find this indentation and parenthesis placement kinda weird (at least the initial lining up under the parenthesis) and would lean towards something like

```
open.add(
    new HeapNode(
        childNode,
        tentativeDistance + heuristicFunction.estimate(childNode, targetNode)
    )
);
```

---

I believe you could choose to annotate `HeuristicFunction` as a `@FunctionalInterface`, but it's not a big deal.

---

```
Collections.sort(successors, (a, b) -> {
    return Double.compare(costMap.get(a), costMap.get(b));
});
```

This can use a single-expression lambda:

```
Collections.sort(successors,
                 (a, b) -> Double.compare(costMap.get(a), costMap.get(b)));
```

which can then be further simplified (thanks @Roland Illig!):

```
successors.sort(Comparator.comparing(costMap::get));
```

Comment: Do you know `Comparator.comparing`? That could be even simpler. `successors.sort(Comparator.comparing(costMap::get))`.